# Slippage in ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, nodejs

Very new to this and can not really find anything on this, these two numbers **50** and **10000** do they = the same slippage?

Is this auto slippage?

I want 20% slippage for a launch today.

```
async function swapTokens(token1, token2, amount, slippage = **"50"**) { //slippage

slippageTolerance = new Percentslippage, "**10000**"; // 50 bips, or 0.50% - Slippage tolerance
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a fix slippage for tokens. If your goal is to set a fixed percent slippage for DEX swaps, the answer is you can't do it.

Slippage is related to liqudity pools and the token reserves in it. Big liquidity pools have low slippage, small lp's have a higher slippage as less reserve is available from the pair token.

Comment: so this should go through on a launch? im really new lol

Comment: The thing is the slippage of your token on the launch day will base on your liqudity pools. But slippage is something you have to worry about only when you buy or sell tokens.  However I assume you misunderstand the concept and function of slippage. I think read some articles about the topic, like this https://dexenetwork.medium.com/what-is-slippage-and-why-does-it-matter-uniswap-example-43e32d712651 @dhandz

Answer (score 0):

You should check the docs of the dex you're going to be interacting with.

I will just assume you're going to interact with a classic UniV2 router fork. You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02#swapexactethfortokens)

What you're referring as slippage is the "amountOutMin" field in the swapExactEthForTokens. Which the uniswap UI automatically calculates for you when sending a tx.

It's possible to calculate this value before sending a transaction but a simpler solution would be to just use "1" as amountOutMin aka 99% slippage.

You should only use this if you're working with small amounts (<0.1 ether) and you're using high gas to protect yourself from sandwich attacks, this is risky but it does a good job in new launches.

**Be **careful** if you're using bigger amounts or slow gas you risk being sandwiched for 99% of the value of the transaction.**

Learn More about sandwich attacks [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/defi-sandwich-attack-explain-776f6f43b2fd).

I would also recommend understanding exactly how the router works before testing anything in mainnet.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the max slippage Amount. When you swap tokens, the price of another coin might change before your order is fulfilled. If you set max slippage amount as 10 percent, you are saying execute the buy order up until price is 10 percent higher. From [Uniswap-docs](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/concepts/V3-overview/swaps)

> The other relevant detail to consider when approaching swaps with the
> Uniswap protocol is slippage. Slippage is the term we use to describe
> alterations to a given price that could occur while a submitted
> transaction is pending.
>
> When transactions are submitted to Ethereum, their order of execution
> is established by the amount of "gas" offered as a fee for executing
> each transaction. The higher the fee offered, the faster the
> transaction is executed. The transactions with a lower gas fee will
> remain pending for an indeterminate amount of time. During this time,
> the price environment in which the transaction will eventually be
> executed will change, as other swaps will be taking place.
>
> Slippage tolerances establish a margin of change acceptable to the
> user beyond price impact. As long as the execution price is within the
> slippage range, e.g., %1, the transaction will be executed. If the
> execution price ends up outside of the accepted slippage range, the
> transaction will fail, and the swap will not occur.
>
> A comparable situation in a traditional market would be a market-buy
> order executed after a delay. One can know the expected price of a
> market-buy order when submitted, but much can change in the time
> between submission and execution.

to set 10 percent slippage amount in uniswap (I never seen slippage set in ethers.js):

```
  import {Percent } from "@uniswap/sdk-core";

  const percentSlippage = new Percent(10, 100);
```